# How to pass a huge amount of variables to a function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, function, variables

I have a huge bunch of variables that should be used in different functions:

```
var one = 20
var two = 30
var three = 40
```

I would like to define these variables just once and then use them in the functions:

```
function calculate(){
   // USE DEFINED VARIABLES HERE
   result = one + two + three;
   return result;
}
```

What would be the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Put the values in the properties of a single object or array, then pass that to the function

Comment: There are about 100 variables – but I didn't want to write them here ... so it is just an example.

Comment: All the more reason to use an object or array as I mentioned above, then :)

Comment: If the variables are declared in the same scope as the functions you don't need to pass them.

Comment: FYI, You cant use numbers as variable names.

Comment: Yes, I know, thanks! The numbers are only for readability. I am sticking in how to explode the object in the function to use it as viable. Any hint? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks you all, I learned a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to try this :

```
<script>
    var a=1,b=2,c=3,d=4,e=5,...;
    //Edited
    //you can use like following code
    function xyz(){
         console.log(a);
    }
</script>
```

And then use it in function.
**Edited**
you don't need to pass in function they are global varaibles just use it by it names.
like shown.